# SQL: How do I find a descript value from one table that's linked to another?

Tags: sql, select

I have two tables (**TableA**; **TableB**) and I need to pull find info from TableB as it relates to an entry in TableA.

**TableA** contains the following:

Unique_ID (*Unique ID applied to every record in this databas*e)

STATE_CODE (*Abbreviation of state that is used as information in the record; a record can only have one state selected but the same state could be applied to multiple records*)

**TableB** contains the following:

STATE_CODE

STATE_NAME

So let's assume it looks like this:

**TableA**:

```
| Unique_ID | STATE_CODE |
+-----------+------------+
|     1     |     TX     |
|     2     |     GA     |
|     3     |     TX     |
|     4     |     MS     |
```

**TableB** would look like:

```
| STATE_CODE | STATE_NAME  |
+------------+-------------+
|    TX      |   Texas     |
|    GA      |  Georgia    |
|    MS      | Mississippi |
```

I need my select statement to pull the STATE_NAME (e.g. "Texas") from TableB based on the STATE_CODE that's applied to the Unique_ID in TableA.

I know I need to relate the STATE_CODE to the Unique_ID and then the STATE_NAME to that specific STATE_CODE but I'm having trouble with my statement.  It pulls the State Name but it repeats it over and over in the results, aka: Texas;Texas;Texas.  I think it's repeating it once for every time that individual record (Unique_ID) was edited/updated.  How do I make it only appear once?

My SQL statement has tp be fairly uncomplicated because I'm writing and running this through a database GUI, not something like SSMS or MySQL.  So a bunch of JOIN and WHERE don't work through the GUI.

```
SELECT STATE_NAME 
from dbo.TableB b
     , dbo.TableA a 
where b.STATE_CODE = a.STATE_CODE 
and a.Unique_ID = {Unique_ID}
```

> I expect the output to just say 'Texas' and instead it says
>   'Texas;Texas;Texas'

I'm from Texas and even I don't want to say it over and over again.

Comment: I should add that I tried to add 'distinct' as part of the statement (aka, Select distinct state_name ..." and it didn't help.

Comment: Your results shows Texas 3 times but one under the other right?

Comment: Correct.  In actuality I'm writing this for a "results list" in a database GUI for other users.  So the list should say: Unique_ID | STATE_CODE |STATE_NAME and instead it says Unique_Id | STATE_CODE | STATE_NAME, STATE_NAME, STATE_NAME;&c

Comment: I believe you will find my DEMO and answer helpful! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This will solve the problem:

```
SELECT STATE_NAME 
from TableB b
     , TableA a 
where b.STATE_CODE = a.STATE_CODE 
and a.Unique_ID = 1
GROUP BY STATE_NAME
```

Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=567f23a02225ac068d99a801ba9b0de1)

But please do note:

> In your question you have given us two tables and some data. When we
>   test your query with that data it returns "Texas" only one time
>   because in TableA you have given us two different values for column
>   Unique_ID for TX. In my first DEMO that you can see above I have
>   changed that for test.

If it is not ok(because of group by and your GUI) then try this:

```
SELECT MAX(STATE_NAME)
from TableB b
     , TableA a 
where b.STATE_CODE = a.STATE_CODE 
and a.Unique_ID = 1
```

Or maybe this:

```
SELECT STATE_NAME
from TableB b
     , TableA a 
where b.STATE_CODE = a.STATE_CODE 
and a.Unique_ID = 1
limit 1
```

Comment: In SSMS that works great, but the weird GUI I'm having to put this into won't allow even group by commands.  If it helps, here's a statement written by someone else in the same GUI that's pulling the distinct file name for a record by its revision number as tied to the Unique ID:   select fi_filename from dbo.fi_file F, dbo.rev_file R where F.fi_file_id = R.fi_file_id and R.Unique_id = {Unique_ID} and r.rev_id = {rev_id}   (i should say; this is a statement that works, unlike mine)

Comment: Well then you can use this statement to put where b.STATE_CODE = a.STATE_CODE  and a.Unique_ID = {Unique_ID} and b.state_name = {STATE_NAME}.  But is this something you need ?